# Dynamically creating over 1k components in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Im recieving from server a JSON containg info about 'colaboradores', for each colaborador i'm creating a panel, like this

```
   var objChildren=[];
   responseObj.map((colaborador)=>{
    var newColab =Ext.create({
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 425,
        margin: 10,
        width: 350,
        border: true,
        bodyBorder: false,
        bodyCls: 'panelColab',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        baseCls: 'image-cropper',
                        style:{
                            backgroundColor:'white',
                            backgroundImage: 'url('colaborador+imageUrl+')'
                        }

                    }
                   //more nested items 
                ]
          }]
        })
      objChildren.push(newColab);
    })
    Ext.getCmp('PanelColab').removeAll();
    Ext.getCmp('PanelColab').add(objChildren);
```

The problem is when this responseObj has like, 1k+ colaboradores, the browser informs me that one page is making my browser slower, and asks me if i want to stop the page from loading (I'm using firefox).

This approach is correct for this quantity of components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the quantity of components may slow down the page.
You should use `DataView` with store containing 1k records instead of creating a 1k components.

[DataView Example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#dataview-multisort)